# How to silently install Global Protect MSI with arguments

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, vpn

i want to install global protect vpn using powershell.
I have below lines to install it

```
Start-Process $PSScriptRoot\Files\GlobalProtect64-5.2.10.msi -ArgumentList "/q /norestart PORTAL='vpn.abc.com'"
```

It gets installed but Portal address are not being set by default as it it asks for manual input.

Any help will be thankfull.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- You can't run MSI files *directly* with arguments. When passing an MSI file for the `-Path` argument of `Start-Process`, it just opens it using `ShellExecute()`, which opens it with the default associated application, without being able to pass arguments to the MSI. Run `msiexec.exe` instead and pass the MSI including its arguments, as the `msiexec.exe` process arguments.
- When calling native processes using `Start-Process`, you need to use **double quotation marks** for quoting arguments. Single quotation marks are passed literally to the process.

  - In simple cases you can use single quotes for the PowerShell command arguments, so you can use double quotes inside of them literally.
  - If you need string interpolation, backtick-escape the inner double quotes, like below (see [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2)).

```sh
# Get full path of msiexec, which is more reliable than depending on PATH env var
$msiexec = Join-Path ([Environment]::SystemDirectory) msiexec.exe

# Start msiexec and wait until it has finished
$process = Start-Process $msiexec -PassThru -Wait -ArgumentList "/i `"$PSScriptRoot\Files\GlobalProtect64-5.2.10.msi`" /q /norestart PORTAL=`"vpn.abc.com`""

# Check if installation was successful
# Exit codes of 0 (ERROR_SUCCESS) and 3010 (ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED) indicate success
if( $process.ExitCode -in 0, 3010 ) {
    Write-Host 'Installation successful'
    if( $process.ExitCode -eq 3010 ) {
        Write-Host 'A reboot is required'
    }
} 
else {
    Write-Host "Installation failed with exit code $($process.ExitCode)"
}
```

Note I've added these `Start-Process` arguments:

- `-Wait` ...to wait until the installation has finished (otherwise the process runs detached!)
- `-PassThru` ...to get a process object back which we can inspect for its `ExitCode` property to determine success state of the installation. See the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/error-codes) for possible exit codes.

Comment: thanks for the reply , i used code changes you shared but still portal address value is not set by default.

Comment: @Shubhkumar Please create a MSI log file using this command line: `"/i \`"$PSScriptRoot\Files\GlobalProtect64-5.2.10.msi\`" /q /norestart /l*v \`"$PSScriptRoot\instlog.txt\`" PORTAL=\`"vpn.abc.com\`""`. Then search for "PORTAL" in "instlog.txt" to see if it is set correctly.

Comment: In logs it says it adding its value, but in vpn it asks for manual input. LOG details : PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PORTAL property. Its value is 'vpn.abc.com'.

Comment: @Shubhkumar Sorry, I'm out of ideas. The command-line and everything seems to be working, so the problem must be somewhere else. Maybe ask in their forum or their support.

Comment: @Shubhkumar If you find a solution, it would be nice if you could post your findings here. Either as an own answer or just drop a comment here so I can add it to this answer.