# Java not installing custom folder "D:\Program Files\Java" through powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am trying to install java on "D:\Program Files\Java" through powershell but it's not installing.
D:\Softwares\jdk-19_windows-x64_bin.msi INSTALLDIR="D:\Program Files\Java"

can any one help me to resole this issue

the package not installing in a "D:\Program Files\Java".
when i try with "D:\ProgramFiles\Java" without space between program files directory it's working, but when it has space between program files directory it's not working.

Comment: Try `Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '-qn', '-i', 'D:\Softwares\jdk-19_windows-x64_bin.msi', 'INSTALLDIR="D:\Program Files\Java"'`. For a more complete example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73880690/7571258)

Comment: i am trying to install Notepad++ package in custom directory, it's not working. 
using below command
Start-Process -FilePath D:\Softwares\npp.8.4.7.Installer.x64.exe '/INSTALLDIR="D:\Program Files\Notepad++"'

can you please help me

Comment: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusage

Comment: @zett42 it's working  D:\Softwares\npp.8.4.7.Installer.x64.exe /NCRC  /D=D:\Program Files\Notepad++ but it's not working when i give this path /D=D:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++
getting below error 
x86 : The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: You need to quote because of space characters: `"/D=D:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++"`